# Java relational operators

Tags: java, operators

In Java, what interface(class) should a class implement(extend) in order to allow two instances of the class to be comparable through relational operators like "<" or ">="?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not possible in Java.

If you want objects of your class to be comparable, implement [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: Im just curious, but could he override the compare to with what ever factors he wants to compare them, and do something like obj1.compareTo(obj2) > 0 which means (obj1 > obj2)???

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to do something more readable than `compareTo()`

Comment: @RMT: That is exactly what implementing `Comparable` does.

Comment: I think they should add this possibility in the future.

Answer (score 4):

Java does not support operator overloading, so you're out of luck. Implementing `java.lang.Comparable` or providing a `java.util.Comparator` is what you're supposed to do.